# Rules to be followed before creating a Hive partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive

As part of my requirement, I have to create a new Hive table and insert into it programmatically. To do that, I have the following DDL to create a Hive table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countData (
    tableName String,
    ssn String,
    hiveCount String,
    sapCount String,
    countDifference String,
    percentDifference String,
    sap_UpdTms String,
    hive_UpdTms String)
COMMENT 'This table contains record count of corresponding tables of all the source systems present on Hive & SAP'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '';
```

To insert data into a partition of a Hive table I can handle using an insert query from the program. Before creating the table, in the above DDL, I haven't added the "PARTITIONED BY" column as I am not totally clear with the rules of partitioning a Hive table. Couple of rules I know are

1. While inserting the data from a query, partition column should be the last one.
2. PARTITIONED BY column shouldn't be an existing column in the table.

**Could anyone let me know if there are any other rules for partitioning a Hive table ?**
Also in my case, we run the program twice a day to insert data into the table and every time it runs, there could be 8k to 10k records. I am thinking of adding a PARTITIONED BY column for current date (just "mm/dd/yyyy") and inserting it from the code. 
Is there a better way to implement the partition idea for my requirement, if adding a date (String format) is not recommended ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mentioned is fine, but I would recommend `yyyyMMdd` format because it sorts better and is more standardized than seeing `03/05` and not knowing which is the day, and what is the month.

If you want to run it twice a day, and you care about the time the job runs, then do `PARTITIONED BY (dt STRING, hour STRING)`

Also, don't use `STORED AS TEXT`. Use Parquet or ORC instead.

Comment: Understood. About rules to be followed to create Hive table partitions, I have mentioned two points. Are those the only two or are there any other rules to be aware of ?

Comment: I wouldn't call those rules. Just syntactically correct and Hive will error at you otherwise. I'm not sure what you're looking for as an answer here. One "rule" I follow is to never have 10000 total partitions in a table, and only partition on columns that are actually going to be queried by. For example, great you get date folders, but if you're scanning a year's worth of data, you don't care about month and day